# Two consecutive hash caracters in URL/href in LaTeX produce incomplete link adress

Tags: urls, href

I'm trying to put a link to a public channel on matrix.org into my LaTeX beamer presentation. The link has the form https://matrix.org/#/#mychannel:matrix.org.

However I observe a strange behavior when using this in an `href` command in my `.tex` file:

```latex
\href{https://matrix.org/\#/\#mychannel:matrix.org}{\#mychannel:matrix.org}
```

is rendered fine on the slide (`#mychannel:matrix.org`) but the link leads to https://matrix.org/#/, i.e., it is cut before the second hash character.

It really seems to be caused by having two consecutive hash characters in the URL since deleting the first `#` character in the URL, i.e.,

```latex
\href{https://matrix.org//\#mychannel:matrix.org}{\#mychannel:matrix.org}
```

results in the link URL https://matrix.org//#mychannel:matrix.org.

Can someone reproduce this behavior? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

### Minimal (not) working example

```latex
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \href{https://matrix.to/\#/\#mychannel:matrix.org}{\#mychannel:matrix.org}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz pointed out, this also happens in an article class and is **not** related to LaTeX Beamer.

Comment: As always you are probably more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and done.

Comment: Seems not related to beamer, same behaviour in article class

Comment: The answer by @Ulrike https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540185/36296 seems to work fine if the `fragile` frame option is used

Comment: Thanks, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, it does and answers my question (which of course is a duplicate of the original question -- sorry for that).

Comment: @OLF No need to be sorry! Duplicates are great sign posts for users with the same problem to find the solution. Not everybody will use the same search terms, so having such signposts will allow more people to find a solution.

Comment: well if someone would open an issue for hyperref then such patches wouldn't get forgotten ....

Comment: For what it's worth, I created one: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/254